# Invalid thread ID parameter: 0 java, how could this happen?

Tags: java, multithreading, solr, solrcloud

I use solr 4.0 and I meet a weird error. I run a solr cloud with one shard three nodes.The `ThreadDumpHandler` tells there is an invalid thread with id 0.

```
ThreadMXBean tmbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long[] tids = tmbean.getAllThreadIds();
log.info("all threads tids:" + (tids == null? "null" :tids.length));
if (tids != null) {
  for (long l :tids) {
    log.info(String.valueOf(l));
  }
  log.info("all thread infos:");
  NamedList<SimpleOrderedMap<Object>> lst = new NamedList<SimpleOrderedMap<Object>>();
  for (long l :tids) {
    if (l > 0) {
      ThreadInfo ti = tmbean.getThreadInfo(l, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      if (ti != null) {
        log.info(ti.toString());
        lst.add( "thread", getThreadInfo( ti, tmbean ) );
      }
    } else {
      log.info("invalid thread id:" + l);
    }

  }
  system.add( "threadDump", lst );
}
```

Comment: Are you saying your log statement "log.info("invalid thread id:" + l);" is getting printed with l as value zero??? or there is some exception ???

Comment: Yes, the the log statement "log.info("invalid thread id:" + l);" print   zero.

Comment: So whats wrong with that? May be one of the long thread id in tids may be zero & thats why it must be printing your log statement? Where exactly you are seeing issue??? Please elaborate

Comment: With a zero thread id "sun.management.ThreadImpl.getThreadInfo(0) " will throw a IllegalArgumentException "Invalid thread ID parameter: xxx". And you can't get the "java.lang.management.ThreadInfo" instance  of this Thread.

Comment: Ohh ok, now I got it. There seems to be open bug for this, so there is no much I can help I think.  Check this    http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6404306